# Optimize SQL Server Query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have to do a query to get the total cost of previous month and compared to current month to calculate the percentage difference.

this is the script:

```
create table #calc 
(
InvoiceDate Date,
TotalCost decimal (12,2)
)

insert into #calc values ('2013-07-01', 9470.36)
insert into #calc values ('2013-08-01', 11393.81)
```

and this is the query:

```
select InvoiceDate, 
       TotalCost, 
       PrevTotalCost, 
       (CASE WHEN (PrevTotalCost = 0)
             THEN 0
             ELSE (((TotalCost - PrevTotalCost) / PrevTotalCost) * 100.0) 
        END) AS PercentageDifference
from (
select a.InvoiceDate, a.TotalCost, 
       isnull((select b.TotalCost 
          from #calc b 
         where InvoiceDate = (select MAX(InvoiceDate) 
                                from #calc c 
                               where c.InvoiceDate < a.InvoiceDate)), 0) as PrevTotalCost
  from #calc a) subq
```

Is there a more efficient way to do it for cgetting the previous month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a ranking function to put more burden on sorts than table scans seems the fastest when using no indexes. The query below processed 6575 records in under a second:

```
SELECT
    Main.InvoiceDate,
    Main.TotalCost,
    PreviousTotalCost=Previous.TotalCost,
    PercentageDifference=
        CASE WHEN COALESCE(Previous.TotalCost,0) = 0 THEN 0
             ELSE (((Main.TotalCost - Previous.TotalCost) / Previous.TotalCost) * 100.00) 
        END
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        InvoiceDate,
        TotalCost,
        OrderInGroup=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY InvoiceDate DESC)      
    FROM
        Test
)AS Main
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        InvoiceDate,
        TotalCost,
        OrderInGroup=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY InvoiceDate DESC)
    FROM
        Test
)AS Previous ON Previous.OrderInGroup=Main.OrderInGroup+1
```

Using nested looping as the case when getting the previous invoice cost in a select subquery proves the slowest - 6575 rows in 30 seconds.

```
SELECT
    X.InvoiceDate,
    X.TotalCost,
    X.PreviousTotalCost,
    PercentageDifference=
        CASE WHEN COALESCE(X.PreviousTotalCost,0) = 0 THEN 0
             ELSE (((X.TotalCost - X.PreviousTotalCost) / X.PreviousTotalCost) * 100.00) 
        END

FROM
(
    SELECT 
        InvoiceDate,
        TotalCost,
        PreviousTotalCost=(SELECT TotalCost FROM Test WHERE InvoiceDate=(SELECT MAX(InvoiceDate) FROM Test WHERE InvoiceDate<Main.InvoiceDate))     
    FROM
        Test AS Main
)AS X
```

Your query processed 6575 records in 20 seconds with the biggest cost coming from the nested loops for inner join

```
select InvoiceDate, 
       TotalCost, 
       PrevTotalCost, 
       (CASE WHEN (PrevTotalCost = 0)
             THEN 0
             ELSE (((TotalCost - PrevTotalCost) / PrevTotalCost) * 100.0) 
        END) AS PercentageDifference
from (
select a.InvoiceDate, a.TotalCost, 
       isnull((select b.TotalCost 
          from Test b 
         where InvoiceDate = (select MAX(InvoiceDate) 
                                from #calc c 
                               where c.InvoiceDate < a.InvoiceDate)), 0) as PrevTotalCost
  from Test a) subq
```

Using indexes would be a big plus unless you are required to use temp tables.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    `current`.`InvoiceDate`,
    `current`.`TotalCost`,
    `prev`.`TotalCost` AS `PrevTotalCost`,
    (`current`.`TotalCost` - `prev`.`TotalCost`) AS `CostDifference`
FROM dates `current`
LEFT JOIN
    dates `prev`
    ON `prev`.`InvoiceDate` <= DATE_FORMAT(`current`.`InvoiceDate` - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01');
```

Screenshot of the results I got: http://cl.ly/image/0b3z2x1f2H1n

I think this might be what you're looking for.

Edit: I wrote this query in MySQL, so it's possible you may need to alter a couple minor syntax things for your server.